# Access to the counter for one tick

Tags: vxworks

I want to know if there is a possibility to get the value of the counter which is used for the TickCounter interrupt.

Purpose:

I want to know the current Tick and the value of this register.

So that I can evaluate this.

For example,

the tick is 12 and the register is 1526. So I can implement a Virtual Clock which use the Tick counter ( base 1ms) and the register so that I have a more precise Clock.

EDIT:

I found this implementation

```
> #ifndef CERT /*******************************************************************************
> *
> * tickGet - get the value of the kernel's tick counter
> *
> * This routine returns the current value of the tick counter.
> * This value is set to zero at startup, incremented by tickAnnounce(),
> * and can be changed using tickSet().
> *
> * RETURNS: The most recent tickSet() value, plus all tickAnnounce() calls since.
> *
> * SEE ALSO: tickSet(), tickAnnounce()
> * 
> * INTERNAL
> * There should be no need to lock interrupts on this one; the compiler should
> * only generate a read from one half of the UINT64 which means that the read
> * can never be interrupted.
> */
> 
> ULONG tickGet (void)
>     {
>     return (ULONG) (vxAbsTicks & 0xFFFFFFFFull);
>     }
> #endif /* !CERT */
```

But I can not access the `vxAbsTicks` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple and correct answer is to just call tickGet().

Comment: But tickGet provides just a resolution of 1 ms

Comment: Correct, which is also what vxAbsTicks has, my understanding of your question was "How can I read vxAbsTciks?" To which the answer is: Call tickGet(). However your post doesn't actually ask a question, I just assumed that is what you wanted to know, but based on this comment I am now not sure what you want to know. So what is your question?